# How can Bloc listen to stream and emit state

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

In my flutter app, I use [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) for state management.

The `bloc` in question uses a `repository`. The `repository` subscribes to a websocket, and new data is added to a stream.

Problem:
My bloc listens to the stream:

```
InvestmentClubBloc({
    required this.investmentClubRepository
  }) : super(InvestmentClubLoading()) {
    onChangeSubscription = investmentClubRepository.onNewMessage.listen(
      (event) {
        emit(NewMessageState(event); // <-- The member "emit" can only be used within 'package:bloc/src/bloc.dart' or in test
      },
    );
  }
```

The problem is that `emit` does not work (I get the warning *"The member "emit" can only be used within 'package:bloc/src/bloc.dart' or in test"*)

How can bloc listen to a stream and emit new states depending on stream events?

Comment: Which `flutter_bloc` version do you use?

Comment: flutter_bloc: ^8.0.0

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Comment: Thank you for the nice question

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should use `emit` in `eventHandler`, use below code to complete your task:

```
abstract class Event {}

class DemoEvent extends Event {}

var fakeStream =
    Stream<int>.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (x) => x).take(15);

class DemoBloc extends Bloc<Event, int> {
  DemoBloc() : super(0) {
    fakeStream.listen((_) {
      // add your event here
      add(DemoEvent());
    });
    on<DemoEvent>((_, emit) {
      // emit new state
      emit(state + 1);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: To clarify: Even though we listen on the stream in the bloc, the bloc should add events to itself? I do recognise this solution would work, but it seems like a lot of overhead code.

Comment: The code is based on your use case. If you have a stream, maybe a `StreamBuilder` can fulfill your requirement though, you don't need bloc then.

Comment: hey, maybe you could help me out here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72716031/flutter-bloc-chat-is-not-refreshing-after-sending-message

Comment: this really given the logic to overcome the issue last night, but hey in the listening part you definetely use a `StreamBuilder`, this is how I achieved the work. Even I have another bloc builder also, so the logic was, I returned the `BlocBuilder` inside `StreamBuilder` builder property, and applied my stream logic between if(snapshot.hasData) {... ...}

Comment: Don't forget cancel subscription in `close`

Answer (score 11):

you should use emit.forEach( )
where forEach must return a state which will be emitted

like this

```
await emit.forEach(yourStream, onData: (dynamic coming_data) {
  return your_state;
}).catchError((error) {
  emit error;
});
```

Comment: hey maybe you could help me out here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72716031/flutter-bloc-chat-is-not-refreshing-after-sending-message